# Fastest Way to scan for Open port in network

Tags: c++, network-programming, port-scanning

How can I scan for a given port number say (8000) in the network?
i tried it using general sockets tcp connection. though it works it takes lot of time time if number of alive ip is more than 15.Goal is to get the list of ip from the network whose given port is open.
This is how i get the list of IP from my network

```
    std::vector<std::string> resultIPList;
    FILE* pipe = popen("arp-scan --localnet","r");
    if(!pipe)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"Unable to open pipe");
        return resultIPList;
    }
    char buffer[128];
    while(!feof(pipe))
    {
        if(fgets(buffer, 128, pipe) != NULL)
        {
            stringBuffer += buffer;
        }
    }
    pclose(pipe);
```

Now My stringBuffer has the ip list. i Have written a parser which extracts ip from the string and give me a vector of those ip. Now i will scan each of them one by one for given port.The function below is for windows, in linux i am doing same using boost::asio

```
    struct sockaddr_in client;
    int sock;  
    client.sin_family      = AF_INET;
    client.sin_port        = htons(portNo);
    client.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr( Ip.c_str() );
    sock = (int) socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    return (::connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *) &client,sizeof(client)) == 0);
```

Comment: can you post some code to show where the slow-down seems to be occurring?

Comment: Since `SOCK_STREAM` does not support multicast (obviously) what do you expect to be the fastest way, except trying all known IP addresses one by one? There's hardly anything else you can do but try to connect and see if it works.

Comment: The general method for speeding up that sort of thing is to spawn a bunch of threads and have each one try and connect. Unfortunately with the TCP retry mechanism there's no good way to speed up each individual attempt which is why you run a bunch in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

You're using the wrong program. Just read the output of netstat.

Comment: You cannot use netstat like that.

Comment: @RafaelBaptista You most certainly can use netstat like that. I inherited a system that had been in production for several years that did precisely that. You have to change the arguments and the parsing, obviously.  Moreover it gives you the ports directly, without a second step.

Answer (score 0):

Use nmap.

Or in a loop, call "connect" to each port using non-blocking sockets. Save all the file descriptors that you collect, check if they connected using "select()";